# Application of valuative criterion

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$According to the first line of the 40th page of *"Introduction to toric varieties"* by William Fulton, when $X$ is irreducible one may assume the image of the map $\Spec K \to X$ is in a given open subset $U$ of $X$, where $K$ is a fractional field of a discrete the valuative ring $R$. This means that, in order to use the valuative criterion, we only have to proof the precondition in a specific case.

Why may one assume the image of the map $\Spec K \to X$ is in a given open subset $U$ of $X$?

Comment: Explaining what you want to prove would help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be an integral scheme separated and of finite type over a field $k$, with generic point $\eta$. Let $K=k(\eta)$ be its function field. I claim that $X$ is proper over $k$ if and only if for every discrete valuation ring $V\subseteq K$ containing $k$ and with fraction field $K$, the valuative criterion is satisfied, i.e. there exists a unique map ${\rm Spec}(V)\to X$ extending ${\rm Spec}(K)=\eta\hookrightarrow X$.

To prove this, by Nagata we may find an integral $X’$ proper over $k$ containing $X$ as a dense open, so that $X$ is proper iff $X=X’$. Let $Z=X’\setminus X$ with any subscheme structure. Blowing up $Z$, we may assume that it is an effective Cartier divisor. Suppose it is nonempty, and let $\xi$ be one of its generic points. Let $V$ be the integral closure of $\mathcal{O}_{X’,\xi}$. This is a discrete valuation ring containing $k$ and with fraction field $K$. The map ${\rm Spec}(V)\to X’$ sends the closed point to $\xi\notin X$, and so the weakened valuative criterion is not satisfied for this choice of $V$.